# How to solve this Error when trying to make details.blade.php page dynamic (laravel 8) " ErrorException Trying to get property 'image' of non-object "

Tags: php, html, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

This is the error ({{$product->image}}) I Get in my Laravel8 project. Please can anyone figure out what is the problem? I am using Laravel 8 and LiveWire for creating this website. My advanced thanks for helping me to solve tis issue.

```
ErrorException
Trying to get property 'image' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel8ecommerce\resources\views\livewire\details-component.blade.php)
```

This is the **web.php**

```
<?php
use App\Http\Livewire\AboutUs;
use App\Http\Livewire\ContactUs;
use App\Http\Livewire\HomeComponent;
use App\Http\Livewire\ShopComponent;
use App\Http\Livewire\CartComponent;
use App\Http\Livewire\CheckoutComponent;
use App\Http\Livewire\User\UserDashboardComponent;
use App\Http\Livewire\Admin\AdminDashboardComponent;
use App\Http\Livewire\DetailsComponent;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/about', AboutUs ::class);
Route::get('/contact', ContactUs::class);
Route::get('/', HomeComponent ::class);
Route::get('/shop', ShopComponent ::class);
Route::get('/cart', CartComponent ::class);
Route::get('/checkout', CheckoutComponent ::class);
Route::get('/product/{slug}', DetailsComponent ::class)->name('product.details');
```

This is the **details-component.blade.php which has the error** only the error part

```
<main id="main" class="main-site">

    <div class="container">

        <div class="wrap-breadcrumb">
            <ul>
                <li class="item-link"><a href="/" class="link">home</a></li>
                <li class="item-link"><span>detail</span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 main-content-area">
                <div class="wrap-product-detail">
                    <div class="detail-media">
                        <div class="product-gallery">
                          <ul class="slides">
                            <li data-thumb="{{ asset('assets/images/products' ) }}/ {{$product->image}}">
                                <img src="{{ asset ('assets/images/products' ) }}/ {{$product->image}}" alt="{{$product->name}}" />
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                        </div>
```

This is the controller **DetailsComponent.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;
use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Product;

 class DetailsComponent extends Component
  {
   public $slug;

   public function mount($slug)
  {
    $this-> slug = $slug;
 }

  public function render()
  {
    $product = Product:: where('slug', $this->slug)->first();
    return view('livewire.details-component',['product'=> $product])->layout("layouts.base") ;
  }
 }
```

This is the productFactory.php that used

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\Product;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class ProductFactory extends Factory
{
  /**
   * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
   *
   * @var string
   */
   protected $model = Product::class;

 /**
 * Define the model's default state.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function definition()
{
    $product_name =$this->faker->unique()->words($nb=2,$asText='true');
    $slug = Str::slug($product_name);
    return [
        'name' => $product_name,
        'slug' =>$slug,
        'short_description' =>$this->faker->text(200),
        'description' =>$this->faker->text(500),
        'regular_price' =>$this->faker->numberBetween(10,500),
        'SKU' => 'DIGI' .$this->faker->unique()->numberBetween(100,500),
        'stock_status' => 'instock',
        'quantity'=>$this->faker->numberBetween(100,200),
        'image' => 'digital_' . $this->faker->unique()->numberBetween(1,22).'.jpg',
        'category_id' =>$this->faker->numberBetween(1,5),
    ];
}
 }
```

Comment: Why do you have space before where condition?

Comment: It could be because `$product` is not an object, but an associative array. Try accessing it as `{{ $produce['image'] }}` instead.

Comment: @HaseebJehanzeb still not working. cant use produce but product is already named as object.

Comment: @Digvijay It doesn't effect for the error even i corrected it..

Comment: Do you even have a `$product` before passing it to view? `dd($product)` and confirm that you have the object.

Comment: I still couldn't solve this problem. Can anyone help me to add the $product object?

Comment: @Perera, can you print `$product` in DetailsComponent.php to the log and add the logged lines in the question as well please?

Comment: @HaseebJehanzeb im really sry.. im very new to php and laravel.. I dont know how to do that?

Comment: @Perera, follow this link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/logging#writing-log-messages (change the Laravel version from top right on the page if needed). There will be a file in which logs are available. The path of that file can be found in `config/logging.php`